# as close to ours as vs closer to ours than

Tags: grammar

Does **as close to ours as** in "Several studies on monkeys, whose immune systems are as close to ours as that of any animal, have been promising, showing a strong and lasting immune response." mean **closer to ours than** ?

Comment: No, it means no other animals are closer, but they could be just as close. In mathematical terms, other animals would be 'equal to or less than' that degree of closeness.

Comment: (1) no other animals are closer, even monkeys or (2) no other animals are closer except monkeys?

Comment: Forget #2. There is no closer. Monkey immunities are close. No other animals have that (immunity) closer than the monkeys, although some could also be at that same closeness.